# pass and remove wrong id

Tags: python, pandas

I want to apply a function to my dataframe and remove rows/ids which give an error. I also want to avoid for loops as they are a bit slow for big dataframes. An example dataframe could look like this:

```py
d = {'a': [1, "wrong_element"], 'b': [1, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d, index=[1, 2])

print(df)
```

Output:

```py
         a       b
1        1       1
2  wrong_element 2
```

```py
    try:
        df['a'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x: x-2)
    except Exception:
        pass
```

desired output:

```py
         a       b
1       -1       1
```

Comment: Why `a` keeps being 1 and not -1 ?

Comment: should be `d = {'a': [1, "wrong_element"], 'b': [1, 2]}`

Comment: you are right, fixed the error, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a `NaN` in case it fails, then drop the `NaN`

```
def operation(value):
    try:
        return value - 2
    except:
        return np.nan
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, "wrong_element"], 'b': [0, 2]}, [1, 2])
df['a'] = df['a'].apply(operation)
df = df.dropna()
```

```
     a  b
1 -1.0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be also be expressed as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, "wrong_element"], 'b': [0, 2]}, [1, 2])

df["a"] = df["a"].replace("wrong_element", np.nan).sub(2)
df.dropna()
```